# One user having multiple card ( php, mysql )

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a question, I am trying to create a way in which the user who is logged in can register multiple cards under his name. I understand the concept but just cannot apply it. So need help.

So basically I have 2 tables one for users and another for the cards, which are as shown.

> new_users
> [image]
>
> user_money
> [image]

So basically i created all this table and most of the information are inserted directly by me for example the orig_id.

So basically what I just want to do is that the user logged in can create multiple cards. Maybe the new_users.id could be equal to user_money.orig_id , but I am not sure how can I make them equal to each other and when a new user registers and enters more cards how can that user id and orig id equal to each other.

This is my controller for login and the controller when user adds a card.

```
public function login(){
            $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
                
                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                    $this->load->view('header_view');
                $this->load->view('body_view');
                $this->load->view('footer_view');
                }else{
                     
                    $email = $this->input->post('email');
                    $password = $this->input->post('password');
                    
                    $this->load->model('main_page');
                   $user_id =  $this->main_page->login_user($email, $password);
                    if($user_id){
                        $user_data = array(
                            'user_id' => $user_id,
                            'email' => $email,
                            'loggedin' => true
                        );
                        
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('loggedin_success','you are loggedin');
                    
                        redirect('main/Admin');
                        
                        
                    }else{
                        
                         redirect('main/login');
                    }
                    
                }
            
        }
```

And this is the function for the new card getting registered.

```
public function insertUserCard(){
            
             $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cardname', 'CardName', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('iban', 'IBAN', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cc', 'CC', 'required|max_length[4]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount', 'Amount', 'required');
                
                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $this->load->view('header_view');
                $this->load->view('admin_view');
                $this->load->view('footer_view');
                }else{
                    
                   
                   
                    $data =  array(
                    'card_type' => $this->input->post('cardname'),
                    'iban' => $this->input->post('iban'),
                    'cc' => $this->input->post('cc'),
                    'amount' => $this->input->post('amount'),
                     'orig_id' => 52 
             /*so the orig id here is randomly added by me */
                );


                    $this->load->model('main_page');
                   $this->main_page->storeCardInfo($data);
                   
                   redirect('main/Admin');
                    
                }
                
            
        }
```

And just incase if needed the models for both the table data being inserted.

```
public function login_user($email , $password){
            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $this->db->where('password', $password);
            
            $result = $this->db->get('new_users');
            if($result ->num_rows() == 1){
                return $result->row(0)->id;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
                
        }
public function storeCardInfo($data){
$insert = $this->db->insert('user_money',$data);
          return $insert;
            
        }
```

So would like if someone could help me on how to get one user have multiple rows in the user_money table.
I am using codeigniter and mysql

Comment: So, is your question about _how_ to get the controller to ensure the `orig_id` is the same as the `new_users.id`?  Or about how to ensure in MySQL that a [`FOREIGN KEY` constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) is followed?

Comment: @Tersosauros yea, I guess basically if the orig_id is equal to new_useser.id then I guess each time I add a card then it will be part of that user, so I guess then it might work

Comment: That sure sounds like a lot of guessing!  Is `$user_data` a **global** variable?  That should be all you need to get the user id?

Comment: Yup $user_data is a global variable, and yea sorry I am new to all this, so basically I do have alot of guessing

Comment: @Tersosauros I put the $user_data in application/config/constant.php in codeigniter file
global $user_data;
not sure if that is right

Comment: Doesn't sound right, as `$user_data` is **not** a _constant_?  It changes with each _user_, and therefore each invocation of the controller.

Comment: @Tersosauros so how can I put it on the controller??

Comment: See my edited answer below.  Basically just add $this-> to both where it is **declared** and then where you want to _reference_ it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `user_id` that is stored into `$user_data` inside of `login()`.

First, to make `user_data` a session variable so that the whole controller can access it, change the line in `login()` which declares `$user_data` as a local variable to assign it to a session variable.

Change:

> ```
>               $user_id =  $this->main_page->login_user($email, $password);
>                 if($user_id){
>                     $user_data = array(
> ...
> ```

To:

```
               $user_id =  $this->main_page->login_user($email, $password);
                if($user_id){
                    $this->session->set_userdata(array(
...
```

**Then**... you can change the line in `insertUserCard()`:

> ```
>                 'orig_id' => 52 
>         /*so the orig id here is randomly added by me */
> ```

to just use the session:

```
                 'orig_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id');
```

---

I think, since you are "new to all this", you should perhaps ensure your MySQL database is setup properly with a [Foreign Key Constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).  (and that you understand how that works)

Comment: Hey I think putting the $user_data in constant file did not help, is there a way to make $user_data a global variable in the controller itself??

Comment: And if I want to delete this user_money table and create it again 
should I do it like this  ??
INDEX par_ind (new_users_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (new_users_id)

Comment: We don't have "_global_" things _inside_ objects (I'm assuming your controller inherits from `CI_Controller`?).  But you can certainly make `$user_data` a field (or other member, if you'd prefer) of the controller class, yes.

Comment: Haha so many questions!  I think if you're unsure about your database structure or operations you should ask a different question (or even submit them for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)).
You also don't _need_ to delete and re-create a table to add INDEX-es or FOREIGN KEY constraints to them.

Comment: sorry, about that I am just a bit confused now, but if you could just help me get the $user_data as a global varible then it might solve all the problem, right now I am getting this error 
Message: Undefined variable: user_data

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to make `$user_data` into a class property (making it _global_ to the whole class, basically).

Comment: I tried it, did not work, 
says A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Main::$user_data

Filename: controllers/Main.php

Line Number: 151

Comment: Are `insertUserCard()` and `login()` in different controller classes!?  Or are they **both** in Main?

Comment: both in main controller

Comment: I can see in netbeans that both user_data in both functions are highlighted

Comment: I'm not sure that netbeans highlights are quite what I'm asking, but nevertheless..  It sounds like some sort of lifetime/execution order problem.  Is `login()` _guaranteed_ to be called **before** `insertUserCard`?  Otherwise the property would indeed be undefined!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102799/discussion-between-masnad-nihit-and-tersosauros).

Comment: can we talk in chat?